# looking for equivalent webform select view module on Drupal 8

Tags: views, 8, webforms

I am a new to Drupal 8

I am trying to make select options with webform submission.

What module do I need?
and
How can I make this select options with that module?

Thank you very much!

imp[image]lement

Comment: I am guessing you are looking for hierarchical selection. If I am right, please check out the Webform Simple Hierarchical Select module. https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_shs

Answer (score 2):

I believe what used to be [webform_views_select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views_select) module is part of Webform core for Drupal 8.

You can search for `entity` and choose any of the following elements

[image]

configure an entity reference view to be use as options

[image]

**NOTE1:**  Due to perhaps [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2890618) entity reference is not recognized by webform the way outlined above, but it should work if core patch in #7 is applied (as confirmed by reports in [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2174633))

**NOTE2:**  Perhaps a work around would be to use `content` or `taxonomy term` instead of a `view` (since view reference is not working) if you don't have great need for views filtering capabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I think I kind of getting idea of how but I am not pretty sure how to do views filter by an entity reference view. Whenever I tried to do this way, it throws me an error saying 'No eligible views were found. Create a view with an Entity Reference display, or add such a display to an existing view.'

Comment: Could you please tell me how to connect reference with View?

Comment: Currently you can not (NOTE1), look at NOTE2 for workaround

Comment: Thank you so much GiogosK!

Comment: I am not sure, is it possible to make taxonomy list with webform submissions?

Answer (score -1):

The [Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) will do this out of the box.

1. Install webform module the usual way.
2. Install the webform_ui module too. It helps a lot in creating new forms.
3. Build your new form.
4. Add Element "select" (to find in the list at "options elements").
5. Add Options you want.

As an alternative you can write your webform-definition in yaml-format.

This looks like:

```
class:
  '#type': select
  '#title': Class
  '#options':
    Geometry: Geometry
    Algebra: Algebra
    English: English
```

Webform module is complex, but can fullfill many needs. There are some helpful videos using webform module.

Comment: I was looking for something about that, and I achieve it  with adding an entity reference display in my desired views, and choose in webform fields settings: Entity select > Content > My Display. Not intuitive but it works